# Different testing keywords in ruby? describe vs test

Tags: ruby

I am a bit confused about RSpec/Integration testing in Ruby.

I have noticed some tests start with keyword test and some start with describe? What's the main difference? is it all RSpec?

for example

```
 test "email should be present" do
      @user.email = "     "
      assert_not @user.valid?
 end
```

and

```
describe 'can set' do
  it 'calories' do
    @dessert.calories = 80
  end
end
```

Edit:
MiniTest vs RSpec 
Pros and cons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `test`...`assert` syntax is typical of MiniTest, sometimes also called Test Unit.

The `describe`...`it` syntax is typical of RSpec.

That said, MiniTest has two kinds of syntaxes, depending on your personal preference:

- the `test`...`assert` which is the classic syntax; it's the one Rails uses for its own internal testing.
- the `describe`...`it` syntax which is called MiniTest Spec; it is very much like a straightforward subset of RSpec's syntax.

If you're working on an existing project, it's good to write using the same syntax as the rest of the project, so your teammates can read the syntax easily.

(Your edit asked for pros and cons -- that's a question that's a better fit for googling rather than Stack Overflow, because there's so much to say about it and there are so many strong opinions. Both are excellent choices and in most projects you'll do great by using whatever the project is already using, or your teammates know the best.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking why/how to use describe:

describe is useful because you can test several thing which are related without repeating yourself. For example, if you wanted to test that desert can set calories and taste, you could do:

```
describe 'desserts' do
  it 'can set calories' do
    @dessert.calories = 80
    ...test...
  end
  it 'can set taste' do
    @dessert.taste = 'delicious'
    ...test...
  end
end
```

When this fails, you will have a message like "Failed desserts can set calories..."

Instead of:

```
  it 'dessert can set calories' do
    @dessert.calories = 80
    ...test...
  end
  it 'dessert can set taste' do
    @dessert.taste = 'delicious'
    ...test...
  end
```

where it is less readable and you are repeating the word dessert.

Answer (score 0):

The `test` syntax is from [MiniTest](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest.html), (Test::Unit in older Ruby versions) in the ruby standard library. `describe`/`it` are from Rspec.